# Regarding Apache nifi - Distrubuted Cache

Tags: apache-nifi, hdf, distributed-cache

Hi I want to work with Distributed Cache in Apache Nifi.

If any could help me with step by step process to implement would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

1) Create a DistributedMapCacheServer controller service and start it

2) Create a DistributedMapCacheClient controller service, configure it to point to the host and port where the server from step 1 is listening, and then start it

3) Use a processor that uses the distributed cache like PutDistributedMapCache

Comment: Thanks you for your reply, Can you please help me regarding how to configure PutDistributedMapCache, also FetchDistributedMapCache processor.

Comment: Also please help me regarding, once if we store the data in cache using putDistributedMapCache, How to access that cached data in the next processors. Thank you

Comment: If you can describe your use case more then I can update my answer with more information. Things like the type of data you are processing, what you want to do with the data in your flow, and what you need to cache would helpful.

Comment: I have a file(f1), I want to pass the one line at a time and parse it(extracting email and timestamp). I want to store this details into the distributedcache.

Now I have one more file(f2) which contains the emailids and datetime. Each value returned from distributedcache(I have get these values), I want to compare it with data in (f2) based on email. If its is found, then I want to make that record for downstream as success, else failed.

If you could help me in this would be great. Thanks